# Poor SQL Server performance when management studio closed

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've noticed a strange behaviour of SQL Server 2008 r2 express:

usually my query execution time is ~650ms, but if I open Management Studio and run any simple query (for example `SELECT * FROM Something`), the execution time becomes ~40ms. If I close management studio this value returns to normal ~650ms

And no matter where the query was executed: from Management Studio or my application (it uses ADO.Net)

ARITHABORT setting has no effect

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The database you are querying probably has "auto close" enabled.

The connection from SSMS stops the database closing. When you close SSMS, the database closes. A subsequent call requires it to be opened.

Auto close is the default for SQL Server Express and is *not* a good idea:

- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217002608/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/06/24/sql-server-best-practices-autoclose-should-be-off.aspx)
- http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/sql-server-auto-close
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706732/what-is-the-auto-close-option-when-creating-a-new-database-in-sql-server-2008